# Why iOS 14 ATT Prompt Won't Work on Simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to make a plugin for my unity project to call new ios 14 ATTracking. It doesn't prompt on screen, why ? I am not getting any error and i know that code goes into the if statement. Trying On Simulator, maybe thats why it doesn't work ?

```
+(void)requestAttPermission:(NSString*)callback
{
 if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
  [ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:^(ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus status)
   {
      UnitySendMessage("SomeGameObject", [callback UTF8String], "");
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Permissions may be denied by user in settings. I'm not sure that one can do this in simulator.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817164/idfa-ios14-returns-denied-without-displaying-auth-popup/62840480#62840480

Comment: Thanks for comment. It was a stupid newbie mistake of mine. Found the answer.

Comment: Note that Apple announced that you've time to implement this permission request until "early next year" as can be read here https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=hx9s63c5 and here https://www.adexchanger.com/mobile/apple-will-delay-its-idfa-changes-in-ios-14-until-early-next-year/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it works on the iOS 14 simulator. What I did wrong was that I thought that the `AppTrackingTransparency.framework` was already added, but it wasn't.

After I added that framework (in Xcode -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries) it worked.