# Requesting tracking authorization on iOS 14 always returns "denied"

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios14

I'm trying to test the iOS 14 tracking popup. It shows up when I test it on the Simulator, but not on a real device (iOS 14.3).

I have already read this post ([IDFA iOS14 returns denied without displaying auth popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817164/idfa-ios14-returns-denied-without-displaying-auth-popup)). But turning on the tracking option doesn't solve my problem.

I made sure:

- To provide a purpose string (`NSUserTrackingUsageDescription`) in the Info.plist
- To actually call `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler:)`
- That the tracking (Preferences > Privacy > Tracking) is turned on

But I don't get prompted when running the app. The `completionHandler` gets called immediately with the `.denied` case.
Also, the app does not even show up on the list of apps using tracking (Preferences > Privacy > Tracking).

[image]

Comment: Did you run your app while "allow apps to request to track" was off?  Have you deleted your app from the device and re-installed it since you turned that switch on?

Comment: I ran it while it was off, I ran it while it was on, and I deleted and re-installed it many times.

Comment: I answer here because it is not a solution. But this issue happens to several of us, I have already found several posts in which the same thing happens that in a device it does not work and in the simulator yes: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671623

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is with OS so you have to update your OS to 14.5.1

Apple released iOS and iPadOS 14.5.1. According to Apple's release notes, the update fixes a bug with App Tracking Transparency that may have prevented some users from receiving prompts from apps.

Release notes for iOS and iPadOS 14.5.1

> This update fixes an issue with App Tracking Transparency where some
> users who previously disabled Allow Apps to Request to Track in
> Settings may not receive prompts from apps after re-enabling it. This
> update also provides important security updates and is recommended for
> all users.

I updated OS from 14.5 to 14.5.1 and now I am getting ATT prompt on first launch.